# Linux man command about [OPTIONS]

Tags: linux, git, manpage

Let's say `git add` command.When I input `man git add`,I get its page.

```
   SYNOPSIS
   git add [--verbose | -v] [--dry-run | -n] [--force | -f] [--interactive | -i] [--patch | -p]
             [--edit | -e] [--[no-]all | --[no-]ignore-removal | [--update | -u]]
             [--intent-to-add | -N] [--refresh] [--ignore-errors] [--ignore-missing]
             [--] [<pathspec>...]
```

I have two quesions:

- `git add --verbose` is same as `git add -v`?
- for other command such as `git`,`python` , `--fullNameA` is same as `-A`? (fullNameA is abbreviated to A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each option in `[--xxx | -x]` characters are the same, so `[--verbose | -v]` means that `--verbose` will do the same as `-v`. This is true for all the `man` pages.